# Is it possible to make an Uninstall software by using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make an Uninstall Software like App Uninstaller in Mac. But, I don't know anything about it. I googled it but, I didn't find any resources that will help to understand how this software works. So, I can't try to make it. Can you please tell me the resources that will help me to complete this task? Can I make it with Python3 or I need to learn JAVA? Where I can get information about this software? or How it works?

I'm not sure about how this software work so, I didn't try anything. I try to find info about it on google but, I found uninstall software recommendation and nothing else. I want a piece of information about how this software works so, I can develop one. Not software recommendations, please.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac's operative system, app are independent from the rest of the computer. If you want to uninstall it just delete it. In that case you can look for how to delete a file in python and try to delete .app . If you want a clean uninstallation I think you need to look for "dependencies" of the .app . I don't know if it help you but here is some link that can be useful

[Delete File in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_remove.asp)

[Working With Files in Python](https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I want to develop software to help me to uninstall apps in my mac completely. There are many in the app store but, I want to develop it as a programmer so I can learn so many things. Thanks, again. I hope so.